# importing database backup to phpmyadmin return #1064

Tags: mysql, php, phpmyadmin

When I tried importing mysql database backup to MySQL using phpMyAdmin 
I got the following error message:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'PK00PK' at line 1

In another post, it says open the sql document and delete weird lines and shall work
where is the sql document that i should open?
i m not a specialist in this.

> PK00PK�"�8B_�5=db.optKIMK,�)�M�H,JL.I-�-N-�--I��J�I���$�d�灅��S�R�s��3�PK�"�8:�h�n�"f2blog_attachments.frm��?k�@�'���K��K����Ԃ
>   *-u(X� 5��bA���E�C�� �^���[|C��Cxɽ�ݷƙ�h��ׄZd�0���f���w�O��A�4@!�B!���L���_�+P'{h[�i=o����p�ċ[_��\p/|]��[��W���[1lɝM0��i�.�;��e�]j,�M]U��Ю�"�Yg�/�SM禉q)p<�7����瘖)���(�̧!�Q�|�0YL@�/��K�PK%�8RDE�DPf2blog_attachments.MYDc``���͍��-,��
>   ҅ܟ��x�{��}˞m�
>   ���MLO�/�*HM�Z�°���a%��K�PK$�8��Y��f2blog_attachments.MYI�������q���L@�����P#
>   <0F̀�^�$�0�r����0\���>K(��� ���@��l��B -�\
>   ��ؘA&%0,bdd�B{���JF�.LY�OX�(F=u��hL%X�Q0
>   �P��(�`�����d�h�2
>   F�H��PK�"�8�^��y�"f2blog_categories.frm�ؽJ�P���G�{S�����c�P_��`��Rup,M�`M�����(�ѡ��E�|
>   �'M�v'<�������ܡpϧP��p��M9�    ���

The database was created in linux and I'm trying to import it to MySQL using phpMyAdmin running in Win 7

Comment: what format has your database backup?

Comment: how are you exporting/importing? you tagged SQL Server and Mysql, any relation between them?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your backup file is a **zip file** (judging by magic bytes `PK` at the beginning) that contains a binary backup of MyISAM tables (a set of files):

```
f2blog_attachments.frm
f2blog_attachments.MYD
f2blog_attachments.MYI
etc...
```

What you need to do to restore your backup

1. Unzip the archive file
2. Stop MySQL
3. Copy unpacked table files to a DB directory (or create a DB first) in the MySQL data directory
4. Start MySQL